# Why the definite article in "with just the suggestion of a smirk"?

Tags: articles, definite-article, idiomatic-language

This sentence from the Oxford Dictionaries Online makes me wonder about its use of the definite article.

> I leaned back in my chair with just **the** suggestion of a smirk on my face. ([source](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/suggestion))

Why is the definite article used here? Of course "with just the suggestion of" is [by no means uncommon](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1920&bih=970&tbm=bks&ei=H0bQXI_2H4m8tgXUjJMo&q=%22with%20just%20the%20suggestion%22&oq=%22with%20just%20the%20suggestion%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i299k1.4799.4799.0.5023.1.1.0.0.0.0.77.77.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.77....0.68DHtsw04EQ). But the indefinite article appears to be a more common option. See [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E2%80%9Cjust%20a%20suggestion%20of%E2%80%9D&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi7kr_zmIfiAhVwdt8KHYegDvsQ_AUIFCgB&biw=1920&bih=970), [Google NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=with%20just%20the%20suggestion%20of%2Cwith%20just%20a%20suggestion%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwith%20just%20the%20suggestion%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20just%20a%20suggestion%20of%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cwith%20just%20the%20suggestion%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20just%20a%20suggestion%20of%3B%2Cc0).

What is the collocation/idiomatic phrase here? Is it "just the + noun"? What are some other examples? Any difference in meaning between the two articles in the sentence at issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As when learning any language, past a certain point, it's best to abandon grammar rules and focus instead on the information the writer or speaker is trying to convey.

Let's take a related example:

> Her face momentarily flashed just **the** hint of a smile.
>
> Her face momentarily flashed just **a** hint of a smile.

In the larger context there is likely no difference in *meaning* between these.  The woman smiled for a moment. That's all.  We move on with the story.

Nevertheless there is always a difference in *nuance* between using the definite and the indefinite article.  You know the definite article is used to talk about things that are *already known* or *mentioned*, or things that are *unique*.  "*The* hint of a smile" relies on the second usage.  It (very slightly) suggests that this wasn't just some ordinary hint of a smile, but represents an *archetypal* hint of a smile.

Don't put too much weight on it, though.  It's a subtle and mostly *stylistic* nuance that, again, does not change the meaning in any significant way.  Let me give another example that does make a difference:

> When talking of Laura, the young men would wistfully remark that hers was **the** face that launched a thousand ships.

"A face that launched a thousand ships" refers to the legendary [Helen of Troy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helen_of_Troy), who was so beautiful that, after she ran off with Paris, a prince of Troy, the Greeks launched an army to bring her back.

(Note: The actual story is more complicated than this, but a full discussion is not relevant here.  If you aren't familiar with the "[Iliad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iliad)", I recommend the BBC series "[Troy: Fall of a City](https://www.netflix.com/title/80175352)", as it sticks fairly close to the source material).

Here the definite article is used because Helen's face is unique and well-known, and the men are saying Laura's face is just like Helen's. If instead we use the indefinite article, we'd have to change the sentence:

> When talking of Laura, the young men would wistfully remark that hers was **a** face that **would have** launched a thousand ships.

which is to say, Laura's face is *an example* of a face like Helen's in that, if she had been alive in those days, she too would have caused an army to chase after her.  The definite article points to a known example that actually had some effect, while the indefinite article makes it a hypothetical with the same presumed effect.

Comment: +1 I guess the genesis of my question is that I wasn't sure a suggestion/hint/trace/tinge/shade of something could be archetypal. _"That is the spirit!" "Hey look at Jimmy! That's the smirk!"_ would strike my ear just fine. But I am not sure it is natural to say _**The** tinge of pessimism is felt in her writing._ Is it?

Comment: @EddieKal  "That's *the* spirit!" is something else, as it's short for something like "That's the spirit (which I want to see you display)" -- that is, a known or specific example.  The one in your question is something else, as it refers to some unstated or nebulous archetype.  It would be fine to say, *"The tinge of pessimism is felt in her writing"*, but readers might be puzzled as to what archetype you are referring.